# ring of integers of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p \ne 3$ be a prime. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $P(X) = X^3 - p$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. I want to show :
$$ p^3 \not \equiv p \: mod \:9 \iff O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$$
It's quite easy to show $p^3 \not \equiv p \: mod \:9 \Longrightarrow O_k = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ by using $disc(1, \alpha , \alpha ^2 ) = [O_k \, : \, \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]^2 disc(O_K)$.
To show that $ O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \Longrightarrow p^3 \not \equiv p \: mod \:9$, one can find some elements in $O_k \setminus \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ when $p^3 \equiv p \: mod \:9$. But the exercise set me on a different path. The first hint was to calculate $3O_k$, we have $3O_k = <3, \alpha - p>^3$, then to calculate the norm of $\alpha - p$, which is $N(\alpha - p) = p^3 -p$. But, even with that, I don't know why this implies that $p^3 \not \equiv p \: mod \:9$. I'm missing something here, and I can't find what.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant is $-27p^2$, not helpful as it is obvious that the primes $q\nmid 3p$ are unramified.

In $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ the maximal ideal above $(p)$ is $(\alpha)$ which is clearly invertible.

It remains to check the maximal above $3$ which is $(3,\alpha-p)$.

- $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ iff $(3,\alpha-p)$ is invertible
- iff $(3,\alpha-p)^3=(3)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$
- iff $(3,\alpha-p)^3=(3)$ in $O_K$
- iff $N(3,\alpha-p)=3$
- iff $9\nmid N(\alpha-p)=p^3-p$.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but there are two things I don't understand : $O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \iff (3, \alpha - p)$ is invertible and $N(3, \alpha - p) = 3 \iff 9 \not | N(\alpha - p) = p^3 - p$.